# it is not working react three fiber on expo

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, three.js, react-three-fiber

```
scripts "build/three.js" and "build/three.min.js" are deprecated with r150+, 
and will be removed with r160. please use es modules or alternatives
```

this warning up on ios-simulator, and not working.

I tried change my version refer to youtube:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8q8H9c9XZ4

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.